# Getting reference to a Dictionary value

Tags: swift

I have a need for a data structure somewhat like this.

```
var d = ["101": [1: "value1"]]
```

I need to modify the inner Dictionary. I can do that using a function:

```
func changeIt(inout dict: [Int:String]) {
    dict[1] = "value2"
}

changeIt(&d["101"]!)
```

Edit: I can also do this:

```
d["101"]![1] = "value3"
```

But I will like to make this change without calling another function. Something like this.

```
var sub = &d["101"]! //Does not compile

sub[1] = "value3"
```

Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: You have already shown the two ways of doing it. It is unclear what you are asking at this point, as you have completely answered your own question.

Comment: The real life data structure is complex. It contains arrays. I can't easily do chained access like d["101"]![1]. I will prefer taking a reference of a value.

Comment: There is no such thing as a reference of a dictionary; it is a value type, not a reference type. The only way to do it is with an `inout` parameter, as you have demonstrated.

Comment: I've been attempting to use unsafe pointers and vars, inner vars for awhile, and it blocks every step of the way and turns the inner dictionaries into immutable... so I would have to say "use Objective C". Or go back to NSMutableDictionary, instead of dictionary types, if you can. With "other people's code" usually that takes rewiring of the ALL of their dictionaries for that data type... but I tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it in a single move except by calling a function with an `inout` parameter, as you've already shown. Otherwise you cannot take a "reference" to a value type in Swift. The normal way is the old-fashioned, simple way, one step at a time: you pull out the inner dictionary, change it, and put it back again:

```
let key = "101"
var d = ["101": [1: "value1"]]
if var d2 = d[key] {
    d2[1] = "value2"
    d[key] = d2
}
```

It's boring but reliable.