# Strategies for adapting from copy-by-reference in Objective-C to copy-by-value in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, pointers, design-patterns

I'm converting a project from Objective-C to Swift, and am running into a lot of bugs based on the change from an NSDictionary being a class that copies by reference to a Dictionary being a struct that copies by value. Here's a simplified example:

```
var recentMessages = [String: [String]]()

func logMessage(_ message: String, forChannel channel: String) {
    let channelMessages = self.recentMessages[channel]
    channelMessages.append(message)
}
```

In Objective-C, that updated the `recentMessages` property. In Swift, that only updates the `channelMessages` variable in the function scope, and I have to copy the change back to the property:

```
var recentMessages = [String: [String]]()

func logMessage(_ message: String, forChannel channel: String) {
    let channelMessages = self.recentMessages[channel]
    channelMessages.append(message)
    self.recentMessages[channel] = channelMessages
}
```

This workaround isn't difficult, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221581/getting-reference-to-a-dictionary-value) called it the best approach four years ago. But it is adding a lot of clutter and I'm afraid of forgetting to apply it every time. Is there a way to more directly replicate the previous behavior?

I could avoid creating the local variable and update the property directly, but that seems like a big limitation and in more complex cases that will make the code hard to read:

```
var recentMessages = [String: [String]]()

func logMessage(_ message: String, forChannel channel: String) {
    self.recentMessages[channel].append(message)
}
```

In cases where the dictionary will be used repeatedly and with predictable keys, I think creating a custom class with properties that support all the keys would solve it. But I have places where a dictionary could include arbitrary keys that aren't predefined, or where a dictionary is only used briefly and creating a class for it would be overkill.

Is there another approach I'm missing that would restore that "copy by reference" behavior my current codebase depends on?

Comment: `self.recentMessages[channel].append(message)` is perfectly fine IMO. I'm not a fan of aliasing mutating dictionaries in-place, but if *absolutely need it* (rethink your design, and see if you actually do), nothing stops you from using `NSDictionary` in Swift, or wrapping `Swift.Dictionary` in a simple `Box<T>` wrapper object

Comment: I forgot about the option to use NSDictionary. And I didn't know about the boxing approach ... that looks interesting (found this article about it: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/92/how-to-share-structs-using-boxing).

Comment: Boxing like this can solve the "I want shared mutable state" problem (beware: you probably don't, and even if you did, it's better to share a class that enforced invariants, rather than raw data structures). Using a box won't solve your syntactic complaint, you would have something like `self.recentMessagesBox.value[channel].append(message)`